# RPyC connect_multiprocess(): Changing 'sync request timeout' not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpyc

I can't change `sync request timeout` in connection established using `connect_multiprocess()` from RPyC module.

I have tried changing `sync_request_timeout` to a different value like this

```
self._conn = connect_multiprocess()
self._conn._config['sync_request_timeout'] = 120
```

or

```
rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG['sync_request_timeout'] = 120
self._conn = connect_multiprocess()
```

or

```
self._conn = connect_multiprocess({'sync_request_timeout': 120})
```

Those changes are visible in `self._conn._config` (shows `{'sync_request_timeout': 120}`), but the base value for timeout actually stays the same (30, as defined in `rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG`). I have checked that by adding print lines to `Timeout` class in `rpyc.lib.__init__.py` .

```
timeout=<rpyc.lib.Timeout object at 0x0000015DD0B50DF0> timeout.finite=True timeout_t=29.99899983406067
timeout=<rpyc.lib.Timeout object at 0x0000015DD0B863B0> timeout.finite=True timeout_t=29.99899959564209
timeout=<rpyc.lib.Timeout object at 0x0000015DD0B85FC0> timeout.finite=True timeout_t=29.997999906539917
...
timeout=<rpyc.lib.Timeout object at 0x0000015DD005C100> timeout.finite=True timeout_t=28.496060132980347
timeout=<rpyc.lib.Timeout object at 0x0000015DD0B51450> timeout.finite=True timeout_t=28.47374176979065
timeout=<rpyc.lib.Timeout object at 0x0000015DD005C100> timeout.finite=True timeout_t=28.47374176979065
```

The only way I could find to change the timeout time is by doing it manually in RPyC's sources, `rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG` dictionary, but I need better solution than this.

I'm running Python 3.10.5 and RPyC 5.3.1.